# How can i get name of the node only not the namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I have this node: . I am using LINQ query to get this node. How can i get this node but not the namespace? I tried using:

```
foreach(var g in xDoc.Descendants(ab + "games"){

         g.Name.ToString();
}
```

This gives ab(whole namespace string) also with the name. Is there a easier way to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [XElement.Name.LocalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the LocalName property:

```
foreach(var g in xDoc.Descendants(ab + "games"){
     g.Name.LocalName;
}
```